# How to get toolStripMenuItem from a Form variable?

Tags: c#

I want to access a toolStripMenuItem from a Form variable pass to a function.

```
public void foo(Form frm)
    {
        frm.controls["toolstripitem1"].checked= true;
    }
```

I know that toolStripMenuItem is not control. my question is how to access this?

"Sorry for my bad english."

Comment: is this an item inside of a `MenuStrip` ? is the `foo` method located in another class?

Comment: foo method is located in another class ! and YES this is an item in MenuStrip.
Generally i want to access MenuStrip in another class.

Answer (score 0):

To access the `MenuStripItem` iterate over the `MenuStrip` control `Items` and check the name matches desired item, this is a simple example with 1 level of items, see below for a recursive example with nested menus, to iterate over 1st level only items:

```
static void CheckMenuItem(Form form)
{
    var menu = form.Controls["menuStrip1"] as MenuStrip;
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menu.Items)
    {
        if (item.Name == "toolStripMenuItem1")
        {
            item.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Recursive example for nested `Menu` to check every item:

```
static void CheckMenuItem(Form form)
{
    var menu = form.Controls["menuStrip1"] as MenuStrip;
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menu.Items)
    {
        if (item.Name == "toolStripMenuItem3")
        {
            item.Checked = true;
        }
        else if (item.HasDropDownItems)
        {
            CheckMenuItemRecursively(item);
        }
    }
}

static void CheckMenuItemRecursively(ToolStripMenuItem menuItem)
{
    foreach (ToolStripItem subItem in menuItem.DropDown.Items)
    {
        if (subItem is ToolStripMenuItem)
        {
            var subMenuItem = subItem as ToolStripMenuItem;
            if (subItem.Name == "toolStripMenuItem3")
            {
                subMenuItem.Checked = true;
            }
            else if (subMenuItem.HasDropDownItems)
            {
                CheckMenuItemRecursively(subMenuItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Arguably the recursive method could be adjusted to also account for a simple 1 level `Menu` but it would be more complicated.